# How do I handle misinputs when using the substring method?

Tags: java, parsing, error-handling, format, substring

I am trying to complete a project that takes a date in the format: *Month Day, Year* Example: December 1, 1990. After taking in this date, I am trying to output it in the format *Month/Day/Year*. The method that I am expected to use is *substring*. I am running into issues with errors when handling misinputs. For example, if there isn't a comma, then an error occurs and the loop is terminated. I am wondering if there is a way to check each value for an error and then continue through the loop if an error is found. Here is my code so far:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
                          // Flag to indicate next iteration
      String lineString = "";
      String month;
      int year;
      int day;
      char comma;
            
      lineString = scnr.nextLine();
      while(!lineString.equals(-1)) {
    
       month = lineString.substring(0, lineString.indexOf(" "));
       day = Integer.parseInt(lineString.substring(lineString.indexOf(" ") + 1, lineString.indexOf(',') ));   
       comma = lineString.charAt(lineString.indexOf(','));
       year = Integer.parseInt(lineString.substring(lineString.length()-4));
   
       System.out.println(month);
       System.out.println(day);
       System.out.println(comma);
       System.out.println(year);
       
       lineString = scnr.nextLine();
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap your code inside while loop in a try-catch block. It will catch your exception without terminating the program.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to catch the exceptions.  That's the way to deal with the potential exceptions from `parseInt`; e.g. when the value isn't a valid integer.

Another approach is to make the code more robust so that the exception isn't thrown at all.  For example:

- check the results of the `indexOf` calls to make sure they are not -1 ... which means "not found", and
- don't make assumptions about the number of characters in each field; e.g.  `lineString.length() - 4`
- consider using `String.trim()` to get rid of additional whitespace.

I think you will need to use both approaches.  The key thing is to think of all the mistakes that the user might make and allow for them.  It is also a good idea to write your own tests.